# Dual Boot Windows 10/Ubuntu: Managing Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

This may be more a Windows question but my reason for asking it is because I want to dual boot Ubuntu, so I'm asking it here.

I know I need to partition my hard drive to install Ubuntu, but I read you can have at max four partitions.  Is this right, and if so why do I have five?  Then, I've been reading about removing partitions to allow for an Ubuntu partition but I don't know what all these partitions are for, so I can't figure out what's OK to change.

If I click on the 100M one, and then click the Explore button, nothing happens.  The c: partition is obvious.  If I click on any of the other three, the buttons to delete, explore, etc. disappear.

I haven't tried to change anything yet because I want to understand exactly what I'm looking at and doing first - any help appreciated!

[This is the laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I4H1NNS) I have: (Samsung Notebook 7 spin 15.6" FHD Touch NP740U5L-Y02US - i7-6500U - 12GB - 1TB)

This is what disk manager looks like: 
[image: Disk Management Partitions]

Comment: Be sure to boot installer in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: With modern UEFI computers, and tera-byte disks, your disk is probably formatted with a GPT partition table, which can have 128 partitions (the older MBR could only have 4 partitions max). What I would suggest you do first is to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD in the `Try Ubuntu` mode, and see if it even works. No use installing if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you need to create a new partition (like D: in ext4/3 type) from C:, to install your Ubuntu. Those disks(500 MB, 12 GB and 1 GB) is the recovery storage created by Windows, I suggest you do not use it, as long as you have sufficient space in C: is 900 GB.

In fact, you can create this ext4/3 files system partition in either Windows or Linux environment.

In Windows, unfortunately, you cannot do so with Disk management, so plz by install MiniTool partition wizard https://www.partitionwizard.com/.

In Linux (I mean your boot into Ubuntu LiveUSB already to install Ubuntu), just follow the steps to Shrink Volume C: and create new partition (around 100 GB size, I guess) to install your Ubuntu.

Lastly, the "EasyBCD" will help you to manage dualboot grub in an easy way.

GL

Comment: Do not create partitions with Windows. It may convert to dynamic partitions which is proprietary to Microsoft. And with UEFI do not use EasyBCD, some do use it for BIOS systems, but not really recommended.

Comment: @oldfred    I had never heard of EasyBCD but the website says it is "Windows 10 and UEFI ready."  Also, when you say not to create partitions with Windows, do you mean you should use something like Partition Wizard instead?

Comment: **You use Windows own `Disk Management` app to resize/create/manage NTFS/MSDOS partitions. You use Ubuntu's `gparted` to resize/create/manage EXT4 (Ubuntu) and other partitions.**